# What is wrong with my find exclude path command?

Tags: linux, shell, find

My folder

```
app
data
node_modules
package.json
package-lock.json
server
```

I want to exclude node_modules

```
find . -path node_modules -prune -o -type f -name "package.json"
```

and serach name in all other paths.
But I got

```
./node_modules/postcss-pseudo-class-any-link/package.json
./node_modules/postcss-pseudo-class-any-link/node_modules/cssesc/package.json
./node_modules/postcss-pseudo-class-any-link/node_modules/postcss-selector-parser/package.json
./node_modules/normalize-range/package.json
./node_modules/run-queue/package.json
./node_modules/regenerator-runtime/package.json
```

and so on

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `name` instead of `path`.  Also, you should explicitly -print to avoid an implicit print of the directory that is being pruned.

```
find . -name node_modules -prune -o -type f -name package.json -print
```

Note that your use of quotes is curious.  For consistency, it seems to me that you ought to write:

```
find "." "-name" "node_modules" "-prune" "-o" "-type" "f" "-name" "package.json" "-print"
```

or even

```
"find" "." "-name" "node_modules" "-prune" "-o" "-type" "f" "-name" "package.json" "-print".
```

If you're going to quote one argument, you might as well quote them all.